# Binding keys with javascript while preventing the browser shortcut keys

Tags: javascript, hotkeys, overriding

I'm making a javascript game and need to bind a lot of keys to different functions. This I know how to do, what I need some help on is over-riding the shortcut keys for the browser. in other-words I want to blur hot keys for the browser and divert them to my application.

Comment: Some keyboard shortcuts in some browsers can't be overridden, so make sure to test all your key bindings in all browsers you need to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you stop the propogation of the event, then you will prevent the browser from catching the event.

an example of this:

```
element.onkeyup = function(e) {
   var ev = e || event;
   //do stuff here, probably with ev.keyCode

   return false;
}
```

Comment: oh really? just like anything else. A bit of an oversight on my part, thanks very much.

Comment: No need for the `ev.preventDefault();`, which in fact will cause an error in IE. If you're using this method of attaching an event handler then the `return false;` does the job in all browsers.